# Keyword not supported: '@"data source'.'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I inserted path of connection string to database(A). The path use for connect database(B). When i select that path from database(A) and try to connect database(B). This is alert message show

> Keyword not supported: '@"data source'.'

This is connectstring in database(A) :

> @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\it_staff\source\repos\MonitorProduction_Client\MonitorProduction_Client\App_Data\monitorclientdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

```
connect_db.conn.Close();
connect_db.conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd_select_connect_string = new SqlCommand("select board_connect_string from[board] where board_id='" + board_id_[0] + "'", connect_db.conn);
        if (cmd_select_connect_string.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
              {
                    SqlDataReader rd = cmd_select_connect_string.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        var board_connect_string = rd[0];
                        connect_db.connb=new SqlConnection(board_connect_string.ToString());  
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You need to share the code which throws the error.

Comment: Are you setting that connection string in web.config? Doing so may cause configuration parser error since you're adding newline in middle of connection string and usage of `@` before opening double quotes which is not allowed.

Comment: But when i change board_connect_string.ToString() is (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\it_staff\source\repos\MonitorProduction_Client\MonitorProduction_Client\App_Data\monitorclientdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True") it can connected

Comment: And why you're using both `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader` on a `SELECT` query? You can just use `HasRows` property after doing `ExecuteReader`, no need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` here. Also check if connection string contains incorrect newline or wrong `providerName`.

Comment: Just check that can query or not. But thank you to give Instructive me. But my problem still not fix it.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto. I found how to solve my problem. I just remove @ and both double quotes from connect string in database. First time i remove it but not work because i have 3 databases and when i select connect_string it is not connect string that i am testing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove @ and both " from connect_string in database

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\it_staff\source\repos\MonitorProduction_Client\MonitorProduction_Client\App_Data\monitorclientdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True